# Cross Domain Authentication with Image Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, authentication

I have been using a 1x1 image to authenticate users across domain names. Recently, it has just stopped working.

The output image is called from the remote server.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng("img.png");
imagecolortransparent ( $im,imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255));
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

As the image is being called, the PHP code verifies if the session exists and if the user is logged in. If so, the request token in validated in the server and the user is logged in on the remote site without the need for the user to re-login on sister domains.

All of the domains share the same server.

This has worked for a couple of years now, but has in the recent months stopped working. I am not sure where to look for the issue. When I check to see if the session is valid on the primary domain, it shows as valid, but when I make the same request remotely, it is not valid. However this did work in the past.

Have the PHP standards changed? or Am I doing something wrong?

Update:
JS Code used to request image:

```
function statCheck() {
    var loopSafety  = $("body").data("loopSafety");     
    if (loopSafety == 0) {
        $("body").data("loopSafety", 1);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/check/",
            data: { tmpToken: tempToken, authType: 'auth'},
            success: function(html){
                var result = html.split("<|>");                                                                                                             
                $("#statImg").html(''); 
                $("#stat").html('');
                $('#stat').append(result[1]);
                $("body").data("loopSafety", 1);            
                onSuccess(result[2]);                       
            }
        });    
        return false;               
    }           
}

function onSuccess(redir) {
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace(redir)},3000);
}
```

Comment: How is JavaScript involved?

Comment: JS is used on the secondary domain to send the authentication request.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code that you use to call the image file. It also needs to be said that using a 1x1 picture is not a secure way to authenticate users.

Comment: I have added some of the code. I don't think it is insecure because all of the authentication occurs server side, and all of the websites have access to the database. The image was the way I used to make a connection between the two sites on the client side (the handshake). Please correct me if I am wrong.